# Is this the leakage current of a MOSFET?

Tags: transistors, analog, integrated-circuit, leakage-current, cadence

I'm trying to understand the leakage current characteristics of a 130nm PDK in Cadence. I set up a testbench by grounding the gate and source terminals of a nmos FET, and setting the drain voltage to a constant (200mV). For a very small size (W/L = 300n/150n), there's about 0.5pA flowing into the drain, and as I increase the drain voltage, the drain current increases linearly. I checked the Ron value through a DC simulation, and Ron is around 600G ohm (200mV/600G = 0.33pA, not too much difference).

I found many posts saying that increasing channel length reduces leakage current. So I increased the W/L to (3000n/1500n). However, the drain current now is 10 times higher.

Is this the right way to measure the leakage current? If not, what is this current I'm looking at?

Comment: Which leakage current are you interested in? A MOSFET is a four terminal device (drain, gate, source, substrate). To understand where the current is flowing you need to measure the current into at least three of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's not surprising, because you also increased the width by a factor of 10x, which will, most likely, dominate the leakage compared to the reduction that could be provided by the length increase alone.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce leakage current? I am designing a switch to control the charging of a capacitor. The leakage current is too high now considering I am using a 1pF capacitor.

Comment: @GeorgeGuo Have you tried T-switches?

Comment: Could you describe this topology? I'm afraid I've never heard of this before. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeGuo figure 9A https://www.analog.com/en/resources/design-notes/selecting-the-right-cmos-analog-switch.html